# How to click on a Button that is not visible

Tags: angular, cypress

I use latest Angular and latest Cypress.

In my application I have a Table with a horizotal scrollbar. In the last Column there is a Angular Material Button, you need to Scroll to the right to see that Button.

[image]

My Cypress Test work only if I manually scroll to the right.

what I tried:

1. cy.get('#myButton').click();
2. cy.get('#myButton').debug().click();
3. cy.debug().get('#myButton').click();
4. cy.get('#myButton').click({force:true});

But nothing of that worked. How I implement a Test that clicks to the right button when its not visible in a Angular Application.

Comment: Cant you directly call the method that is bound to the button in your test?

Comment: Does the button element exist? Can you debug to see that the button is detected after `cy.get ('# myButton')`?

Comment: Cypress should be able to find any element that is in the DOM IIRC, if it can't click on it then the button isn't loaded. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

If `cy.get('#myButton').click({force:true})` fails then the element is not in the DOM yet, and scrolling is required to load it.

It's quite hard to activate a scrollbar in javascript, but try scrolling "3/4 button" leftward.

```js
cy.contains('3/4 button').scrollTo('left')  // try to trigger 4/4 button load

// or maybe 
cy.get('myTable').scrollTo('left')

cy.get('4/4 button')
  .scrollIntoView()
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```